# translationY doesn't change bounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-toolbar, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a flexible toolbar using the ObservableScroll [library](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)
 following the code that he [wrote](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/observablescrollview-samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples/FlexibleSpaceToolbarScrollViewActivity.java), only that I want to use a RecyclerView instead of a ScrollView.

here's the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vFlexible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="72dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="test"/>
</FrameLayout>


<com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableRecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/rv" />
```

and here's the code:

```
package test.itayrabin.toolbartest;

import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableRecyclerView;
import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollViewCallbacks;
import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ScrollState;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {

private View vFlexibleSize;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private TextView tvTitle;
private int flexibleSize;
public static final String TAG = "FlexibleTest";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    tvTitle.setText(getTitle());
    setTitle(null);

    final ObservableRecyclerView recyclerView = (ObservableRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this));
    recyclerView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);

    flexibleSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.flexible_space_height);
    int flexibleAndToolbar = flexibleSize + getActionBarSize();

    vFlexibleSize = findViewById(R.id.vFlexible);
    vFlexibleSize.getLayoutParams().height = flexibleAndToolbar;

    //recyclerView.setPadding(0,flexibleAndToolbar,0,0);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {
    update(scrollY);
}

@Override
public void onDownMotionEvent() {}

@Override
public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {}

protected int getActionBarSize() {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    int[] textSizeAttr = new int[]{R.attr.actionBarSize};
    int indexOfAttrTextSize = 0;
    TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, textSizeAttr);
    int actionBarSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(indexOfAttrTextSize, -1);
    a.recycle();
    return actionBarSize;
}

private void update(final int scrollY){
    vFlexibleSize.setTranslationY(-scrollY);

    int adjustedY = scrollY;
    if (scrollY<0){
        adjustedY = 0;
        Log.i(TAG,"Scroll Y <0 - " + scrollY);
    } else if (flexibleSize < scrollY){
        adjustedY = flexibleSize;
        Log.i(TAG,"scrollY is bigger than flexibleSize - " +scrollY);
    }

    float maxScale = (float) (flexibleSize - mToolbar.getHeight()) / mToolbar.getHeight();
    Log.i(TAG,"maxScale is " + maxScale);

    float scale = maxScale * ((float) flexibleSize - adjustedY) / flexibleSize;
    Log.i(TAG,"scale is " + scale);

    tvTitle.setPivotX(0);
    tvTitle.setPivotY(0);
    tvTitle.setScaleX(scale + 1);
    tvTitle.setScaleY(scale + 1);

}
```

What's basically happening here is there is a Frame layout at the top of the screen, consisting of a LinearLayout that has the Toolbar on top and a view underneath it that expands and collapses when we scroll. below that I have the recyclerView.

I collapse the flexibleView when there is a scroll in the update method by setting it's TranslationY.

The problem is that when I scroll and the FlexibleView collapses the recyclervies's padding stays, or the LinearLayout doesn't change it's bounds, or something is making the recylcerview stay in it's location and not go up sticking to the edge of the toolbar FrameLayout.

Does anyone have any ideas how do I fix this?